# Share a photo on user's facebook profile on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to share a photo from my app to facebook, exactly like Instagram does by toggling on "Share on facebook", where the user result in having a beautiful large photo on his wall.

I followed exactly the "Custom Stories with Open Graph" tutorial on Facebook at:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph

I even downloaded Facebook's sample project on iOS that follows the tutorial code. I copied this code and replaced the namespace, action and object with mine. Here's the code:

```
// stage an image
  [FBRequestConnection startForUploadStagingResourceWithImage:image completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {
      NSLog(@"Successfuly staged image with staged URI: %@", [result objectForKey:@"uri"]);

      // instantiate a Facebook Open Graph object
      NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];

      // specify that this Open Graph object will be posted to Facebook
      object.provisionedForPost = YES;

      // for og:title
      object[@"title"] = @"Roasted pumpkin seeds";

      // for og:type, this corresponds to the Namespace you've set for your app and the object type name
      object[@"type"] = @"fbogsample:dish";

      // for og:description
      object[@"description"] = @"Crunchy pumpkin seeds roasted in butter and lightly salted.";

      // for og:url, we cover how this is used in the "Deep Linking" section below
      object[@"url"] = @"http://example.com/roasted_pumpkin_seeds";

      // for og:image we assign the uri of the image that we just staged
      object[@"image"] = @[@{@"url": [result objectForKey:@"uri"], @"user_generated" : @"false" }];

      // Post custom object
      [FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
          // get the object ID for the Open Graph object that is now stored in the Object API
          NSString *objectId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
          NSLog(@"object id: %@", objectId);

          // create an Open Graph action
          id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
          [action setObject:objectId forKey:@"dish"];

          // create action referencing user owned object
          [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"/me/fbogsample:eat" graphObject:action completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if(!error) {
              NSLog(@"OG story posted, story id: %@", [result objectForKey:@"id"]);
              [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OG story posted"
                                          message:@"Check your Facebook profile or activity log to see the story."
                                         delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                                otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            } else {
              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
              NSLog(@"Encountered an error posting to Open Graph: %@", error.description);
            }
          }];

        } else {
          // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
          // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
          NSLog(@"Encountered an error posting to Open Graph: %@", error.description);
        }
      }];

    } else {
      // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
      // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
      NSLog(@"Error staging an image: %@", error.description);
    }
  }];
```

Here's the log:
[image]

The problem is, the posts **never** makes it to my wall, **even though the object appears created in the Objects Browser**. Going to my app dashboard on developers.facebook.com and open graph, I see the story exists, but no stories have been shared even though the app says so.

What's wrong ? Help, please!

Comment: Have you turned on explicit sharing for your OG action? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#explicitsharing

Comment: Hum, how would you do that? I don't see mention of explicit sharing property when sharing a story using api calls. I'm creating: id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject]; and I don't see any way to set that BOOL on the action

Comment: Ah! For those having the same problem: "[action setObject: @"true" forKey: @"fb:explicitly_shared"];" Thanks!